# 'x' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I want to overload insertion and extraction operator in codeblocks.
Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<conio.h>  

    enter code here

 using namespace std;

 class point
 {
    private:
    int x,y;
    public:
    point(int a, int b){
    a=x;
    b=y;
    }
 friend istream &operator >>(istream &i, point &p);
 friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &o, point &p);
 };

 istream &operator>>(istream &i, point &p)
 {
     cout << "Enter the coordinates of x and y";
     i >> x >> y;
     return i;
 }
 ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, point &p)
 {
     cout << "coordinates are :";
     o << x << endl;
     o << y;
     return o;
 }

 void main()
 {
     point p1(3,4);
    cin  >> p1;
    cout << p1;
 }
```

And I am getting the following errors:

> 'x' was not decleared in this scope
>
> 'y' was not decleared in this scope

Please help to overcome this problem .

Comment: In function point() x variable is unknown.

Comment: `i >> x >> y;` -> `i >> p.x >> p.y;`

Comment: Also in your constructor:    ` a=x;
    b=y;` you probably meant the opposite: `x=a; y=b;`, but better yet use `point(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) { }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['was not declared in this scope' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056093/was-not-declared-in-this-scope-error)

Comment: closing a question if you problem is solved is always a good idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously they won't be visible to your operator functions as they are declared in a class.

You need to access them through the object p. E.g. `p.x` and `p.y`

Answer (score 0):

```
point(int a, int b){
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```

Comment: and access using p.x and p.y

Comment: This answer (very subtly) points out a problem with the code, but doesn't actually explain the problem being asked about.