# What is " Variable ' i ' was not declared in scope " in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, scope

While practicing c++ code, I used the variable that was declared in the for loop.i want it to use it again in another for loop. But it showed me an error that the

> `variable i was not declared in scope`

and I tried the same loop in Eclipse IDE it showed me

> `the symbol i was not resolved`.

The sample code looks similar to this:

```
 #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            cout<<i;
        }
        for(i=10;i<20;i++){
            cout<<i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to declare it again in the second loop, because it goes out of scope after the first loop.

Comment: `i` only exists *inside* the first loop, because you declared it there. Trying to use it in the second loop gives you the error. If you moved the `int i;` to before that loop, or redeclared it in the second loop, it would work.

Comment: works for me. I'm using Visual Studio 6 ;)

Comment: Looks like JS's `var` and `for` loop. :-)

Comment: @virgesmith: Yes, that's a bug in that compiler.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I know. I havent actually used VS6 for donkeys years but the pain of fixing all that non-compliant stuff is still fresh.

Comment: actually not my buisness, but imho the edit was not really an improvement (in particular the question in the title changed to something that certainly has a duplicate)

Comment: @user463035818 Actually they had a reason to change the title. So it's ok

Comment: the question that is now in the title has an answer for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056093/was-not-declared-in-this-scope-error (I would vote for duplicate if that wouldnt close the question immediately), but the title before was better in describing your exact question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare the variable for each scope:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<i;
    }
    for(int i=10;i<20;i++){
        cout<<i;
    }
}
```

After the first loop, there is no `i` anymore. You can try what the compiler says and see that this will fail:

```
int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<i;
    }
    cout<<i; // Error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`i` only defined within the *scope* of the first `for` loop, so it needs to be re-declared in the second one.

Early Microsoft C++ compilers had a bug where the `i` leaked into the scope of the `for` loop to produce effectively

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

Comment: do you mean `i` leakes **out** of the scope of the for loop? Or was the bug actually about `i` of one loop leaking into the scope of the next loop?

Comment: @user463035818: I've put the equivalent code in. As far as I can remember the initialisation of `i` took place in the loop itslef.

Comment: interesting, guess that can cause all sorts of confusing bugs, on the other hand there should be an error if `i` was already declared in the outer scope

Answer (score 3):

By writing `for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {...}` you declare the `int i` inside the `for` loop scope and it only has effect inside the `for` loop.

If you want to re-use the `int i` then you should place it outside of & before any `for` loop:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout<<i;
    }
    for(i=10; i<20; i++){
        cout<<i;
    }
    cout<<i; // <- fine, 20
}
```

Or, simply repeat the declaration with each `for` loop then `int i` in `for` loops are totally different variables.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout<<i;
    }
    for(int i=10; i<20; i++){
        cout<<i;
    }
    //cout<<i; <- oops!!! error
}
```