# Why is my function not returning type Point?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ syntax, for this function closest_coin below I get a "use of undeclared identifier" for the `return result` line in the `closest_coin` function. Why is this happening when I declare the type inside the if statement when assigning the variable result?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Point{
    public:
        int x,y;
        Point(int x_position, int y_position){
            x = x_position;
            y = y_position;
        }
        int calculate_distance(Point other_point);
};

int Point::calculate_distance(Point p2){

    int x_distance = abs(x-p2.x);
    int y_distance = abs(y-p2.y);
    int result = x_distance-y_distance;

    return result;
}

Point closest_coin(Point your_position, vector<Point> coin_positions){
    int closest_distance = -1;
    int distance;

    for (Point coin : coin_positions){
        distance = your_position.calculate_distance(coin);

        if (distance>closest_distance){
            Point result = coin;
            closest_distance = distance;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Look where you declare `Point result` and where `return result;` is. Those are different scopes

Comment: So I need to add "Point result;"  Inside the closest_coin(){ } brackets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['was not declared in this scope' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056093/was-not-declared-in-this-scope-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I declare the type inside the if statement

When you declare anything inside `{` and `}` that variable is only valid there. It won't work either if you declare it outside the `if` but inside the `for` loop for the same reason.

You can just declare the `result` variable in the beginning of your `closest_coin` function and only assign inside the `if`.

**Note**: your `Point` class has no default constructor. Therefore, you will have to set some value when declaring. Your `closest_coint` method becomes

```cpp
Point closest_coin(Point your_position, vector<Point> coin_positions){
    int closest_distance = -1;
    int distance;

    Point result(0,0);
    for (Point coin : coin_positions){
        distance = your_position.calculate_distance(coin);

        if (distance>closest_distance){
            result = coin;
            closest_distance = distance;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to define result here as, ```Point result;``` without initializing the class? I know this would throw an error as I have written here. Just for future reference, Thanks. EDIT: didn't read your answer fully, default constructors..will read about them.